# WCF Self-Hosted Windows Service HTTPS Multiple Domains Same IP:Port

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-binding, http.sys

So I want to have multiple WCF Self-Hosted Windows services listen on 443 over HTTPS, different IP addresses.

My base URL is something like:

- **red**.contoso.com:443/api
- **blue**.contoso.com:443/api

However, when I try to register red.contoso.com:443/api it takes the entire  namespace!!

Is there no way to instruct WCF to NOT try to register the entire https://+:443 namespace, but only red.contoso.com:443 (or the IP for red.contoso.com -- e.g. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443) so that I can have the other service listen on blue.contoso.com:443 (or the IP for blue.contoso.com -- e.g. yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:443)?

Can WCF self-hosted not support this scenario?